# Issues with SQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables and result as shown in the image below: MySQL DB

[image]

What would be best way to join the two tables so we get the result as shown above.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, desc FROM table2) as T1 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM table1) as T2 ON T1.id = T2.id
```

I guess my SQL is not working.

Comment: Table2 as t1, and table1 as t2... Scary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` with `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT t1.id, COALESCE(t2.desc, t1.desc) AS desc, t1.D1, t1.D2
FROM table1 as T1 
LEFT JOIN table2 as T2 ON T1.id = T2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a left join with `coalesce` to prioritize table 2's values if they are present, but fallback on table 1's values if not.

```
select t1.id,
       coalesce(t2.desc, t1.desc) as desc,
       t1.d1, t1.d2
  from table1 t1
  left join table2 t2
    on t2.id = t1.id
 order by t1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ifnull](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html):

```
SELECT t1.id, ifnull(t2.desc, t1.desc) AS desc, t1.D1, t1.D2
FROM table1 as T1 
LEFT JOIN table2 as T2 ON T1.id = T2.id
```

`coalesce` or `case .. when` is also possible. All together with the `left join`